# How does Google use information provided to their AutoML Natural Language service?

Tags: google-natural-language, google-cloud-automl

I am writing a privacy policy for a web site which uses Google's AutoML Natural Language service. What does Google do with the information we provide to that service? Does anyone have a link to a terms of use document or privacy policy which explains it precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on automl NL at Google.
The training data is only used to train the user's model and is deleted automatically after a short period of time. The trained model is used only for the user who provided the model and will live util the user deletes it.
For inference, please see this: 
https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/data_usage